# Получить все коллекции монго кроме этих

Tags: php, mongodb, коллекции

Пытаюсь запросом получить список всех коллекций, кроме site и stat_site

```
$collections = $db->getCollectionNames(array('name'=> array('$nin' => array('site','stat_site'))));
```

вылезает список всех коллекций, и эти тоже. Как их правильно исключить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод [listCollections](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.listcollections.php), указав в опции filter требуемые ограничения:

```
$collections = $db->listCollections(array(
    'filter' => array(
        'name' => array(
            '$nin' => array('site', 'stat_site')
        )
    )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$collections = $db->getCollectionNames();
unset($collections(array_search('site', $collections)));
unset($collections(array_search('stat_site', $collections)));
```